# Exclude children of the first span tag inside div

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, phantomjs, casperjs

I am building a simple web scraper. This is the website I am scraping - http://www.home.com/pro/c/oho,-NI. My scraper clicks on every link with a class name of `pro-title` and extracts data from the web page it enters (eg: http://www.me.com/pro/home/marcelle-services)

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    logLevel:"verbose",
    debug:true
});

var jsonObj = {};
var links;
var name;
var paragraph;
var contact;
var description;
var location;
var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
var regex = new RegExp(expression);

casper.start('http://www.home.com/ro/c/oho,-TN');

casper.then(function getLinks(){
     links = this.evaluate(function(){
        var links = document.getElementsByClassName('pro-title');
        links = Array.prototype.map.call(links,function(link){
            return link.getAttribute('href');
        });
        return links;
    });
});
casper.then(function(){
    this.each(links,function(self,link){
      if (link.match(regex)) {
        self.thenOpen(link,function(a){
          var location = this.fetchText('div.info-list-text');
          //var location = document.querySelectorAll("div.info-list-text")[1];
          var contact = this.fetchText('span.pro-contact-text');
          var description = this.fetchText('div.profile-about div');
          this.echo(location);
          //this.echo(contact);
          //this.echo(description);
        });
      }
    });
});
casper.run(function(){
    this.exit();
});
```

The above code produces this output,

```
                                       Professionals

                                Interior Decorators

                Contact: GuilbeauLocation: 5007 Wyoming Ave.Nowoah, MI 45786
```

I want to omit the `div.info-list-text a span:first` selection so that the word `Professionals` is not logged.

Comment: Please include the markup that you're talking about in your question. Pages may change and your question and the answer will lose all value for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might as well include jQuery to make your life easier when selecting elements. One solution for this:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
   logLevel:"verbose",
   debug:true,
    clientScripts:  ['jquery.js']
});

var jsonObj = {};
var links;
var name;
var paragraph;
var contact;
var description;
var location;
var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
var regex = new RegExp(expression);

casper.start('http://www.houzz.com/professionals/c/Nashville,-TN');

casper.then(function getLinks(){
 links = this.evaluate(function(){
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName('pro-title');
    links = Array.prototype.map.call(links,function(link){
        return link.getAttribute('href');
    });
    return links;
});
});

casper.then(function(){
 this.each(links,function(self,link){
  if (link.match(regex)) {
    self.thenOpen(link,function(a){

       // I just manually extracted the stuff you wanted with jquery selectors
       var txtYouWant = casper.evaluate(function() {
          var desiredText = $($("div.info-list-text").first().find("span a span")[1]).text();
          desiredText += $($("div.info-list-text")[1]).text();
          desiredText += $($("div.info-list-text")[2]).text();
          return desiredTxt;
       });
    });
  }
});
});
```

EDIT:

Make sure you fix this part:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
   logLevel:"verbose",
   debug:true,
   clientScripts:  ['jquery.js']
});
```

Comment: Test the jquery selectors in your browser's dev tools, and you'll see that they work. Did you download jquery and put it in the right directory?

Comment: Yeah they work, but I don't think they are working within CasperJS. I downloaded jquery into the right directory.

Comment: And is it named jquery.js? Test if $ is defined in the evaluate function.

Comment: Please see my edit...I missed a bracket in my original post that was needed to include jquery.

Comment: I included the bracket when I ran your code the first time. It didn't work.